# Close the Browser when click on a button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a project to order online and when the client finishes ordering I want to add a button to close the browser and return to WhatsApp messages where start ordering  how can I close the browser when the client clicks not only one tap?

how can I close the browser when the client clicks not only one tap?

Comment: How do you open the browser? Show how you've tried to close the browser.

Comment: What exactly is the browser showing?  Is it a page you control or 3rd part site?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is want to add a link to your website that sends the user back to your Whatsapp page. This does not involve manually closing a browser. Instead, you need to add a link to your webpage.

For example:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=18005551212&text=Hi!%20I%20want%20to%20increase%20my%20sales!

When clicked, this will send the user back to Whatsapp phone number 1-800-555-1212. You will need to change this to your phone number.

For additional information, Whatsapp instructions can be found at:

https://blog.wearedrew.co/en/3-steps-to-integrate-whatsapp-with-your-website

Comment: It's Working Perfectly Thank You ... Sorry to be late